# Select item from combo box WPF from view model in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following view model:

```
public sealed class FileViewModel : AbstractPropNotifier
{
    private string _path;
    private CategoryViewModel _category;

    public string Path
    {
      get
      {
        return _path;
      }
      set
      {
        _path = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Path));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
      }
    }

    public string Title => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path);

    public CategoryViewModel Category
    {
      get
      {
        return _category;
      }
      set
      {
        _category = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Category));
      }
    }
}
```

and Category view model:

```
public sealed class CategoryViewModel : IEquatable<CategoryViewModel>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public EMyEnum Value { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(CategoryViewModel other)
    {
       return Title.Equals(other.Title) && Value == other.Value;
    }


    public static CategoryViewModel From(EMyEnum eCat)
    {
       return new CategoryViewModel
       {
          Title = eCat.DescriptionAttr(),
          Value = eCat
       };
    }
}
```

I set data context to my view model like:

```
public sealed class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
      Files = new ObservableCollection<FileViewModel>();
      Categories = GetCategories();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FileViewModel> Files { get; set; }

    public CategoryViewModel[] Categories { get; set; }

    private CategoryViewModel[] GetCategories()
    {
      var enums = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EMyEnum));
      var list = new List<CategoryViewModel>();

      foreach (var en in enums)
      {
        EMyEnum cat = (EMyEnum)en;
        list.Add(CategoryViewModel.From(cat));
      }

      return list.ToArray();
    }
}
```

and

```
_model = new MainViewModel();
DataContext = _model;
```

and XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Categories" Source="{Binding Categories}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and in `DataGrid` element

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Category}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Categories}}" Header="Category" Width="2*" DisplayMemberPath="Title"/>
```

The dropdown is populated correctly but cannot select automatically from dropdown a specific `Category`, means the `Category` column from Datagrid is empty.

I expected to select automatically from dropdown with correspondent `Category`...

Where is my mistake ? I tried with `SelectedItemBinding` and `SelectedValueBinding` but same issue. Nothing selected from dropdown.

---

**To be clear:**

For a file, I set a category but nothing is selected:

[image]

But dropdown has items:

[image]

Comment: It is `FilesViewModel` observable collection. Means `Files` property from `MainViewModel`

Comment: So the `Category` property of the `FileViewModel` isn't set when you select an item in the `ComboBox` and leave the row?

Comment: The issue I refer to is that dropdown (Categories collection) does not select automatically item accordingly with `Category`'s value of `FileViewModel` object. Visually, for specific FileViewModel, the dropdown is empty (no item selected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably different instances of `CategoryViewModels` in your `MainViewModel` compared to the ones in the `FileViewModels`.

You should either override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your `CategoryViewModel` class or make sure that you set the `Category` property of each `FileViewModel` to a `CategoryViewModel` that's actually present in the `CategoryViewModel[]` array of the `MainViewModel`.

Comment: @SnakeEyes: Try to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods instead. It's these methods that WPF uses to compare the objects. I edited my answer.

Comment: One more quick question: how to store selected value from dropdown in `Category` object of `FileViewModel` ?

Comment: It should be stored in the `Category` property using the `SelectedItemBinding`.

Comment: If I change a value from dropdown, seems that `Category` value of file object is the old one not selected one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195998/discussion-between-snake-eyes-and-mm8).